# JavaScript/Jquery Dynamic RegExp generation

Tags: javascript, regex, dynamic

I've searched this place a lot, and I'm stuck at that my regular expression works, but not dynamically.

**id_name** is the string that is picked dynamically. Then, the regexp should replace the match with a single var, which is in "vals". For some reason, when I code the regexp without the variable, it works as intended. I think I might do something wrong with the conversion to a regexp object.

Original String:

```
obj = values.replace(/{name}(.*?){\/name}/, 'igm');
```

Regexp Object:

```
        re = '\/{' + id_name + '}(.*?){\\/' + id_name + '}\/';
        regexp = new RegExp(re, 'igm');
        obj = values.replace(regexp, vals);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't know it was that easy :), it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `/` and you also don't need to escape the character if you are constructing the regex via constructor:

```
re = '{' + id_name + '}(.*?){/' + id_name + '}';
```

Comment: Worked really well. What I do not understand, and I've tried to cross check the reference on it, but saw nothing about: (regexp is still in my eyes one of the most difficult things)

When I replace the { } for % and /%... it works fine the first time it comes across it, but the second time, it stops replacing:

`
re = '%' + id_name+ '%(.*?)%/' + id_name + '%';

regexp = new RegExp(re, 'igm');  
values = values.replace(regexp, '');
`

Comment: @user1520088: I don't know - it is possible that you have something strange in `id_name` that is recognized as regex.

Comment: I'm not certain it's what's in there. Since it replaces everything else fine. It's just when I replace the {} for %% when it goes wrong for the second time. I forced the id_name into a string. Even hardcoded, it has a problem. I have to add, whatever it's replacing is a email footer. The first part is purely text based with a <br> here and there. The second one has a TABLE layout. like `%name%<tr><td>{name}John Doughnut{/name}</td></tr>%/name%`. 
Whenever when unchecked the option, it suppose to remove the %name% section. Works in the first part, not second (within table).

Comment: Do you want to just remove `%name%` or do you want to remove everything inside including the `%name`?

Comment: Everything in between the %name% --- %/name% really :)

Comment: @Laelfaert: Can you post a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem you have, plus the expected output? I really have no idea the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: I have it online at : [link](http://generator.castle-v.com/) It's all in one document. When you click generate, it parses. (when the checkboxes are unchecked, they should not display the %/xx%. It's about the lowest function in the source (all in one doc, since im still building :), not optimized tho :S )

Comment: @Laelfaert: Oh, the match spans across lines. You should have given example from the beginning. Change `(.*?)` to `([\s\S]*?)`, since `.` will not match new line character.

Comment: Cheers.. i had absolutely no clue it could be that. RegExp is still very much magic to me. I am not able to wrap my fingers around it (for more then 10 years :S ). Cheers for the heads up man! :)

Comment: I've had to put the project slightly aside. But I've been busy again with it. Unfortunately, I've used the code and it doesn't work still. I've tried multiple combinations, but so far, no luck.

The updated code is: `re = '%' + trigger + '%([\s\S]*?)%/' + trigger + '%'; `


EDIT: Got it to work. The code should've been: 

`re = '%' + trigger + '%([\\s\\S]*?)%/' + trigger + '%'; `

totally forgot about the double backslash when using '' and "" because it escapes. Silly and stupid me, but it works :)